# Collection to DataTable

Tags: c#, gridview, collections, datatable, converters

I am trying to convert a Collection to a DataTable, so that I can bind it to a gridview. (If there is another way of doing this, I am open to ideas)

This is what the collection looks like:

```
public class CustomerCollection 
{
    [JsonProperty("customer")] 
    public IEnumerable<customer> Customer { get; set; } 
}

public class customer  
{ 
    [JsonProperty("customer-name")] 
    public string strCustomerName { get; set; } 
    [JsonProperty("customer-address")] 
    public List<string> lCustomerAddress { get; set; } 
}
```

The end result looks like this:

[image: Collection]

The problems that I am getting occur when trying to bind it to the gridview. I get errors like:

```
Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
```

And when using a Helper class to try and convert it to a DataTable, I get:

```
The type arguments for method 'CollectionHelper.ConvertTo<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind your grid view to the `Customer` collection property:

```
gvDisplay.DataSource = customers.Customer;
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you were binding it directly to the `customers` variable which is of type `CustomerCollection` which in turn (despite its name) is not a collection at all, it's just a simple .NET class with a `Customer` property.

Comment: You might probably find a better naming for your classes and properties as they are pretty misleading. For example the `CustomerCollection` class should probably be named `CustomerData` and the `Customer` property should probably be named `Customers` because it is a collection of `customer`.